# Bootstrap - covering or overlapping columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, overlap

I want to cover or overlap two columns.

Having one on the **left side (6 columns)** and one on the **right side (6 columns).**

My result should be: **left side (8)** and **right side (6)** - overlapping for **2 columns**.

I have looked into Bootstrap documentation for offset/push/pull properties but got no proper result.

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a negative margin-left to the smaller div. (I added the panel class so the overlap would be visible).  For the sake of the example, I just added the css in a style attribute.

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="col-lg-8 panel">this is the left div</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 panel" style="margin-left: -16.7%;z-index:-1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;this is the right div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. How do we know that 20% equals two columns?

Comment: The math for one column would be 100/12=8.333333333333333.  So, 16.66666666666667 should be the equivalent of two columns.  I've never seen a reason to overlap columns, so this was just a shot from the hip.  I had only tried it with trial and error and hadn't attempted to match two columns, exactly.  After experimenting with it, margin-left:-16.7% overlaps and margin-left:-16.6% wraps.

Comment: Can you please edit your previous answer, so we are not missguiding others by 3,3%? :) Thanks.